# Amcharts5 cursor click event

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

Currently my javascript code has an XY chart of amcharts5, with at least one 'series', but can have more.
I need to add a click event on the graph cursor, so that when I click on it, I receive a console.log indicating the x point and all the y points where I clicked, considering only the vertical line of the cursor, that is, when I click on a graph point, I want all the Y values ​​related to the X point (it can have more than one, considering that we have more than one 'series')

I tried this, similar to what i found in another thread, but it didn't work:

```
  cursor.events.on("click", function(ev) {
  var x = ev.target.getPrivate("positionX");
  var y = ev.target.getPrivate("positionY");
  
  var dateX = xAxis.positionToDate(x);
  var valueY = yAxis.positionToValue(y);
});
```

Comment: Also running into this problem and have found that the click event on the cursordoes not appear to be  consistant.